# Find max value in CSV column using d3.max

Tags: javascript, d3.js

After using data().enter().append() in D3.js, individual columns/values in a dataset can be retrieved by simply using `d.valuename`. But I want to find the maximum value in a CSV column for a linear scale. Since the scale is not preceeded by any data calls, I'm really uncertain on how to specify the right column from which to find the maximum value.

This is my failed attempt. What do I substitute `d.column1` with?

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function (data) {

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(d.column1)])
    .range([0, 960]);
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, I got a bit further by looking at [a similar example](http://bl.ocks.org/4062085). I don't understand why my code is not working now.

```
 d3.csv("file.csv", function (data) {

 data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.column1 = +d.column1;
 });

 var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.column1; });

 var x = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, max])
     .range([0, 960]);
```

**EDIT #2:**

In case the problem derives from the data itself, here's a snippet. I have tried removing all quotes, and also keeping the quotes for everything but the top row, but nothing works.

```
"product", "price"
"bread",20
"meat",100
"meat, sausage",200
```

**EDIT #3:**

Ok, I promise, last edit. But just to be absolutely clear; I'm using the x-scale to determine the width of the bars in a bar chart: `.attr("width", x)` and the scale returns NaN.

Comment: You're edited example seams to be correct for determining the max. For example, the following jsfiddle shows it working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/HCDJu/

What exactly is not working?

Comment: Perhaps it's got something to do with the data source. See my latest edit for a sample of the data in my CSV file. What do you think?

Comment: The problem is that the width of my bars returns NaN. If I skip the scale and let the width be a function of the data, like `.attr("width", function (d) {return +d.column1})` it works like a charm. But the `d3.max` is not as willing to treat the rows as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized what the problem was. No wonder we couldn't figure this one out together. All the code above is fine. It's just that when I called the x-scale to determine the width of my bars, I didn't specify which column in the data would be input to the scale. I had

```
.attr("width", x)
```

But now I changed that row to:

```
.attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.column1); })
```

Thanks for your help and patience.

Answer (score 8):

To explain why your code is working:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.column1 = +d.column1;
});
```

This above statement turns all your column1 values into an integer (the + sign in front of d.column1 coerces the type to a Number).

Once your values are all numbers, d3 can now compare them as numbers instead of strings. This way 10 will be larger than 9. If they were strings, "9" would be larger than "10".

```
var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.column1; });
```

The above line simply takes the max of your data array. Since your data array is made up of objects, d3 has no way of knowing how to compare one object to another. The second parameter is a function that gives d3 a value to each object so that d3 can compare each object. In your case you are telling d3 to use column1 to determine the max value. This is similar to a comparator function.

Comment: Shoot misread your edit and thought you asked why your code was working. Not why your code wasn't working

Comment: Well at least I learned something, so thanks :) http://jsfiddle.net/activescott/HCDJu/

Comment: Thanks benr, and sorry if I was unclear in my edit above. It's weird though, that the code doesn't work now, right? I posted a snippet from my CSV file in case that's where the problem lies.